# UnEscape Xml in Groovy

Tags: xml, groovy, elasticsearch, escaping

I am trying to UnEscape an xml in Groovy :

```
&lt;student&gt;&lt;age value=&quot;20&quot;&gt;&lt;/age&gt;&lt;/student&gt;
```

to

```
 <student><age value="20"></age></student>
```

but I am not able to find any library that can accomplish this. I tried using `groovy.json.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJavaScript` but it doesn't help.

There is one library `groovy.xml.XmlUtil` which has `escapeXml` method but it doesn't has `unescape` method.

My purpose of usage is to use this groovy script in Elasticsearch v1.3.2 which contains `groovy-all-2.3.2.jar`

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Think you mean 'escape'

Comment: Very sorry , actually i meant UnEscape only but by mistake reversed input and output earlier(now corrected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a trick using the built-in XmlSlurper class and no additional libraries:

```
value = "X &amp; Y &lt; Z"
// wrap the string in made up tags to create
// well-enough-formed XML for the XmlSlurper
xml = "<foo>${value}</foo>"
println xml
root = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
root.toString()
```

Result: 'X & Y < Z'

Comment: I tried to check if it works and yes it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can just use commons-lang from apache for this.

```
// For Grails (2), add:
//
//     compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3'
//
// to your build config. For a groovy script, we can do:

@Grab('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3')
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils

def xml = '&lt;student&gt;&lt;age value=&quot;20&quot;&gt;&lt;/age&gt;&lt;/student&gt;'

def unescaped = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(xml)
```

Easier than writing and maintaining your own ;-)

Comment: Actually my purpose of usage is to use this groovy script in Elasticsearch v1.3.2 which contains groovy jar , since i am not familiar with grails, I don't know how can i  make use of grails(if allowed) with your code and if it is possible how it will take org.apache.commons-lang.StringUtils ( do i need to put jar for it myself in Elasticsearch folder)?

Comment: Why did you tag this question as grails then?

Comment: my bad but it was auto-suggested so i thought may be people knowing about that can tell. I didn't know earlier the relation between groovy & grails, just heard the name groovy with grails before.

Answer (score 3):

Not the most efficient and complete solution but I think it will do the job:

```
def s = '&lt;student&gt;&lt;age value=&quot;20&quot;&gt;&lt;/age&gt;&lt;/student&gt;'

def u = s.replaceAll(/&lt;/, '<')
         .replaceAll(/&gt;/, '>')
         .replaceAll(/&quot;/, '"')
         .replaceAll(/&apos;/, "'")
         .replaceAll(/&amp;/, '&')

assert u == '<student><age value="20"></age></student>'
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution and can you please tell why it is not complete? According to me you have handled all escaping scenarios for xml. Isn't it?